# Rails 4.0 selected value on form_for select with multiples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using a form with a select multiple :true, it submits fine but on edit it does not properly select values.

```
f2.select :question_answer_multi, qd[:question_answer_options].split(','), {}, multiple: true, class: 'form-control'
```

This same setup works correctly with a single select, but not with my multiple select?

qd[:question_answer_options] provides a comma separated string entered by users on a different form used to generate this one.

Comment: try remove `split(',')` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding this into my model:

```
serialize :question_answer_multi
```

This saves the array in a format that Rails can read, allowing it to be called normally in the edit form like this:

```
f2.select :question_answer_multi, qd[:question_answer_options].split(','), {}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
<%= f2.select :question_answer_multi, options_for_select(qd[:question_answer_options].split(','), array_of_values_to_be_selected), {}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: true } %>
```

replace 'array_of_values_to_be_selected' with the array of values that needs to be pre selected in the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<%= f2.select :question_answer_multi, qd[:question_answer_options].split(','), {:include_hidden => false},{ multiple: 'multiple', class: 'form-control'} %>
```